# Subtract minutes from date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to subtract a number of minutes from a date.
Something like:

```
select @minute=1440
Select @datetime='2014-02-05 23:27:51.413'

select @datetime- @minute
```

Comment: select DATEADD(minute,-1440,'2014-02-05 23:27:51.413')

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because if you'd typed that title into the google search box rather than the question title box you'd have found your answer a lot quicker.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to manipulate the datetime values. If you want to subtract the values then you can use the parameter with negative value like this

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, -@minute, @datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,

```
DECLARE @MINUTE INT =1440
DECLARE @DATETIME DATETIME='2014-02-05 23:27:51.413'
SELECT @DATETIME AS INPUT, DATEADD(MINUTE,-@MINUTE,@DATETIME) AS RESULT
```